# Regex for matching everything except first and last word

Tags: javascript, regex

I would to exclude first and last word from the string in JS regex. Please suggest.

Example strings

```
QueueName default_queue end
QueueName default queue end
```

I would like to match `default_queue` and `default queue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use capture groups

```
var str = "QueueName default_queue end"

var matchArray = str.match(/^\w+\s+(.+)\s+\w+$/) // capture with paranthesis

console.log(matchArray[1]) // default_queue
```